# Reduce Line Spacing in Span

Tags: html, css

See the span below:

```html
<div style=" position:absolute; top:37.6pt; left:0.8pt; background-color:; border:0pt solid black; width:234pt;">
<div  align="left" ><span style=" white-space:pre-wrap;  font:normal 8pt Arial; color:rgb(0,0,0);">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</span></div> 
</div>
```

Span by default is showing too much line spacing, i want to bring the line spacing like the text below:

```html
<div style=" position:absolute; top:37.6pt; left:0.8pt; background-color:; border:0pt solid black; width:234pt;">
<div  align="left" ><div style=" white-space:pre-wrap;  font:normal 8pt Arial; color:rgb(0,0,0);">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</div></div> 
</div>
```

The limitation i face is i cannot use "div" instead of span, neither can i play around with "display" attribute, so is there any way of reducing the line spacing in span without the display attribute.. ideally "line-height" property, but that doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ideally "line-height" property, but that doesn't seem to work..

I will work if you set line-height not on the span, but on the parent container:

```html
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div align="left" style="line-height: .4em;">
        <span style="white-space: pre-wrap; font: normal 8pt Arial;">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPD.** @sai kumar spotted interesting detail about importance of the CSS rules order. In order `line-height` to work on span it should be put after `font` property. Order is important here because `font` is a combined property which also includes `line-height` in it. So in this case `font` defined after `line-height` would overwrite it with default value of `line-height: normal`.

Answer (score 2):

`line-height : Xpx;` for the `span`, will do the trick. `X` being a integer value. `FYI`

**UPDATE**

It does work, order of giving style is important.

```
 font:normal 8pt Arial; 
 color:rgb(0,0,0);
 line-height: 9pt;
```

Specify the `line -height` as you require

*I do not know why the order matter, but the job is done. May be the font is overidding some of the properties*

Comment: It's a good catch. Order is important because `font` is a combined property which also includes `line-height` in it. So in OP's case `font` defined after `line-height` would overwrite it with default value of `line-height: normal`.

Answer (score 0):

You must give line height to the parent div i have updated your code you can check

```html
<div style=" position:absolute; top:37.6pt;line-height:14px; left:0.8pt; background-color:; border:0pt solid black; width:234pt;">
<div  align="left" ><span style=" white-space:pre-wrap;  font:normal 8pt Arial; color:rgb(0,0,0);">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</span></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This reduces the heights of line boxes but does not bring it to the same as for the simple `div`. (You can also see this by inspecting the dimensions of the elements in a browser’s developer tools.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the position attribute and its value as absolute:

```
<div style=" position:absolute; top:37.6pt; left:0.8pt; background-color:; border:0pt solid black; width:234pt;">
<div  align="left" ><span style=" white-space:pre-wrap;  font:normal 8pt Arial; color:rgb(0,0,0);position:absolute;">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange problem caused by **inline font settings**. To circumvent it, set font properties in a `style` element or in an external style sheet instead of setting them in `style` attributes.

The problem is independent of the positioning of the wrapper elements and on the `white-space` setting. But it depends on the way font properties are set. It can thus be demonstrated in a simplified setup:

```html
<style>
.foo { font: 8pt Arial }
h2 { font-size: 100%; margin: 1em 0 0 0 }
</style>
<h2>span</h2>
<span style="font:normal 8pt Arial;">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</span>
<h2>div</h2>
<div style="font:normal 8pt Arial;">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</div>
<h2>span, but font not set inline</h2>
<span class="foo">Your statement shows claims for medical care only after we've received and processed the claim. The claim in question may not have been received yet or it may not be finalized. There may be instances where your claims are not showing up because Health Statements have recently been added to your plan.</span>
```